# how to convert functions into a JQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, frontend

I want to learn how to write Jquery plugin.This is my normal function and convert it into jquery plugin could you suggest me how to do this.

So that I can easily understand how to convert function to the plugin.

```
function probe_Validity(element) {
  var validate = true;
  $(".required-label").remove();

  var warnings = {
    text: "Please enter Name"
  };

  element.find(".required").each(function() {
    var form_Data = $(this);

    if (form_Data.prop("type").toLowerCase() === 'text' && form_Data.val() === '') {
      form_Data.after('<div class="required-label">' + warnings.text + '</div>').addClass('required-active');
      validate = false;
    }
    if (validate) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }

    $(function() {
      $(".required").on("focus click", function() {
        $(this).removeClass('required-active');
        $(this).next().remove();
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Why would you add `$(function() {
            $(".required").on("focus click", function() {
                $(this).removeClass('required-active');
                $(this).next().remove();
            });
        });` every time you found a required element??? It does not belong inside your function

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this project [jQuery plugin boilerplate](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate)
Consider this as a base plugin definition, look it up, follow the steps and adjust them to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to do you just use

```
jQuery.fn.theNameOfYourFunction = function() {}
```

then you can get the element the function is called on like this :

```
var element = $(this[0])
```

so with your function it would be :

```
jQuery.fn.probe_Validity = function() {

        var element = $(this[0]);
        var validate = true;
        $(".required-label").remove();

        var warnings = {
            text: "Please enter Name"
        };

        element.find(".required").each(function() {

            var form_Data = $(this);

            if (form_Data.prop("type").toLowerCase() === 'text' && form_Data.val() === '') {
                form_Data.after('<div class="required-label">' + warnings.text + '</div>').addClass('required-active');
                validate = false;
            }
            if (validate) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

            $(function() {
                $(".required").on("focus click", function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('required-active');
                    $(this).next().remove();
                });
            });
        });
    };
```

this can be called like so :

```
$('#id').probe_Validity ()
```

Comment: However this still adds the same event listener EVERY iteration.

Comment: thank you so much for this Joost_96. it's working fine.